# Feedback controlled by potentiometer

Tags: potentiometer, feedback

I'd appreciate some help with the following section in this question:
[image]
Here's an attempt:

Since it's shunt-shunt feedback I figured I could write:

\$V_o/V_s=-10=A(R_1+R_2+R_L)/(1+AB)\$, where \$A\$ is the open-loop gain. But I am having difficulties assessing \$A=V_o/i_s\$. Could its value simply be \$R_L\$?

Comment: Why RL in the equation? Also, the port is connected to port A or B ?

Comment: @G36 I am expected to determine whether the potentiometer is to be connected to port A or B (possibly after finding the values of R1 and R2). As for RL, I am told "a load resistance \$R_L=100K\Omega\$ is connected between output terminal and the ground". Hopefully that's all clearer now and you'll be able to assess my attempt and help.

Comment: For me, the RL is not the part of the feedback network

Comment: @G36 Okay, but aren't RL and (R1+R2) still connected in series, hence Vs=is(RL+R1+R2)? And what would the value of A be? 1/2?

Comment: In series? No, way.

Comment: @G36 So how would you describe it? Are you claiming they're not in series as the feedback must be "broken" down to R11 and R22?

Answer (score 0):

I see it this way:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ff7dXp.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: I see. Well, I still need to determine the relation between Vo and Iin, don't I? In order to do that, don't I need to plug in R11 in parallel and R22 (also in parallel)?

Comment: How may I determine A=Vo/is?

Comment: I'm not sure but you could treat R1 as a Rs and R2 as Rf.

Comment: Good idea. In that case, wouldn't you get \$\frac{-R_f \cdot \gamma \cdot R_s}{1+\gamma}=-10\$, where \$\gamma\$ denotes the gain of the \$A\$ unit in the feedback?